# Dump raw image data

Tags: c++, windows, image, raw-data

I have an image stored in memory in the form of raw bytes i.e. I have a `char*` pointing to the memory location of the image data. Now, I need to somehow validate if the image data is legitimate.

What I have currently tried is to simply dump the bytes into a file. I tried dumping into 3 types of files, but no luck:

```
std::ofstream ofs;
ofs.open("Image.raw", std::ofstream::out);
ofs.write((char*)imgData, imageInfo.imageLen);
ofs.close();
// Have also tried "Image.tiff" and "Image.ppm"
```

Is there any way to view the contents? Just to mention, I am writing this code on Win platform. A few years back, I remember doing the similar thing on MAC OS X, which yielded successful results!.

Comment: What is a raw image format ? yuv ? rgb ? As ppm, tiff, bmp are containers,  you need to add the enveloppe.

Comment: If you want a simple container format, look at the PNM formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it straight out as RGB in binary like you already have - say to a file called `image.rgb`.

Then use `ImageMagick`, which is installed on most Linux distros, and available for OSX and Windows to convert it to PNG, JPEG or something more common:

```
convert -size 300x400 -depth 8 image.rgb result.png
```

or

```
convert -size 300x400 -depth 8 image.rgb result.jpg
```

You will need to tell `ImageMagick` the dimensions of the image as above because they are obviously not embedded within a raw file like they would be in a JPEG or PNG with a header.

If the filename you choose does not end in .rgb, you will need to prefix it with RGB: like this

```
convert -size ...   RGB:something.bin   result.png
```

Comment: I tried using ImageMagick on Windows, but I think there is something missing. When I run the command as mentioned by you, I am getting the error: "invalid argument for option -size".

Comment: Microsoft ships a program called `convert` too - it converts filesystems to NTFS. Try using the full path to ImageMagick's `convert`, e.g. C:\ImageMagick\convert -size ....` or whetever you installed it.

Comment: Geez! I already know 'convert' is pre-installed for filesystem conversions. I am using the ImageMagick command only and then getting the mentioned error.

Comment: Here's the error: "convert.exe: invalid argument for option `-size': 637*876 @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2755."

Comment: Use `637x876` rather than with an asterisk.

Comment: Excellent! Glad to be of service - if your image lacks contrast, you can add in `-auto-level` just before the output filename.